# Sorting dictionary in python, value in descending order, if conflict then by key

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as

```
r = {1: 4, 2: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 10}
```

I want to sort this based on value(Descending order), if conflicts then sort by key(Ascending order). 
i.e the output should be

```
[6 ,1 ,2 ,4 ,5]
```

How do i do this?

Would the above be easy, if I had List instead of dictionary? i.e.

```
r = [(1, 4), (2, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 10)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to `sorted()` to produce a tuple for each element:

```
sorted(r, key=lambda k: (r[k], -k), reverse=True)
```

or

```
sorted(r, key=lambda k: (-r[k], k))
```

Now the keys will be sorted (in reverse) based on the `(value, negative key)` tuple, or sorted (forward) on the `(negative value, key)` tuple. Tuples are sorted lexicographically, so ties between equal values are broken by sorting on the key. By negating either the value or the key, you affect a reverse sort.

Demo:

```
>>> r = {1: 4, 2: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 10}
>>> sorted(r, key=lambda k: (r[k], -k), reverse=True)
[6, 1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> sorted(r, key=lambda k: (-r[k], k))
[6, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```